# Differentiating a period of an elliptic curve under the integral sign

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves, complex-integration, elliptic-functions, elliptic-integrals

Let
$$g = \frac{27J}{1 - J},$$
where $J$ is the absolute invariant, and define
$$\Omega = \int_{\gamma(J)} \frac{dz}{\sqrt{4z^3 + g(z + 1)}}.$$
Here, $\gamma(J)$ is a contour in the complex plane that encloses any two of the three roots of $4z^3 + g(z + 1)$ and does not go through the third. Since the roots are given in terms of $J$, the path $\gamma(J)$ is a function of $J$ (or $g$).

I would like to differentiate $\Omega$ under the integral sign with respect to $g$. Is it permissible? Could someone point me to a theorem I could use or help me prove it directly?

Comment: To make sure that I understand what you are asking: write $$4 x^3+ g x  + g = 4 (x - e_1)(x-e_2) (x-e_3), $$
with $e_i$ distinct. 
Write $S= \mathbb C \cup \infty$ (the Riemann sphere). Your curve $\gamma =\gamma(J)$ is some simple curve in $\mathbb C \setminus \{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$, which has $e_3$ (say) in the same component of $S \setminus \gamma$ as $\infty$, and the other two $e_i$ - $e_1$ and $e_2$, say - in the other (bounded) component of $S \setminus \gamma $.  Correct?

Comment: @peterag Suppose $e_1, e_2 \in \gamma$, $e_3 \not \in \gamma$, say, and $e_3 \not \in \partial \gamma$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\partial \gamma$? Is not $\gamma$ a closed curve - i.e. $\partial \gamma = \emptyset$? And again, just to be absolutely certain - since your clarification was not what at all as I expected: as an example: say, 'by abuse of notation',  $ \gamma(t ) = e^{it}$ for $t \in [0,2\pi]$, is a parametrization of $\gamma = \gamma (J)$, and $e_1 =1 , e_2= -1$, and $e_3=0$, or $e_3 = 2$?

Comment: I had expected, with the previous example of $\gamma$, that $e_1$ and $e_2$ to be arbitrary, distinct, with norms less than $1$, and $e_3$ to have norm greater than $1$.

Comment: To be clear: matching up your explanation with my example:your  "suppose $e_1$, $e_2\in \gamma$", means in my example  $\gamma$, that $e_1, e_2$ have norm 1 - this is what I was illustrating in my 'what do you mean.." post. This does not match the question's "encloses," at least as I understand the word 'enclose' to mean - my 'I had expected' comment illustrates my understanding - 'enclose' should mean that the norm is less than $1$.

Comment: @peterag What is your question? To enclose means to surround. To enclose two roots by $\gamma$ means to surround two roots by $\gamma$. Two of the roots are the interior points of $\gamma$ and the third is an exterior point of $\gamma$.

Comment: I was not happy because your comment says $e_1$ and $e_2 \in \gamma$.  But you don't seem to mean that - you mean as I understood it, with my example $\gamma$ that the norms $e_1$ and $e_2$ have norm less that $1$. and $e_3$ has norm greater than $1$.  Do you agree?  please say yes or no - If yes, I certainly think I can reply to YOUR  question (can one differentiate ...), time allowing, and will unless some else does. .

Comment: @peterag No, and I do not think I can make it any simpler: encloses means surrounds. Have a look at this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531064/differentiating-a-contour-integral) and Christian's answer.

Comment: Well, I would have answered very much as Christian did - I don't know why you aren't happy with it... best wishes....

Comment: @peterag I am happy with it. I just have not rewarded his answer, yet. You may and I will reward your answer. Thanks